# List of restricted ports for mobile devices and operating systems?

Tags: php, web-services, mobile, tcp, udp

I'm trying to obscure a normal http soap call to a device so that it doesn't use port 80. My only reason why is that the device doesn't do https.

So I picked a random port (43) to address an intermediate server to send the message and discovered that the port is blocked on iOS and android.

Is there a list that is readily accessible?

Comment: that isn't a very good reason to not use port 80.  Do you have any other justification?

Comment: When you pick a random port, make sure it's about 1000.

Comment: My main reason is that the soap message contains some <secure> information that has to be sent in XML as open text in the free... I know it's not ideal, and I'm working to get the vendor to change their device, and until that happens ill be in beta, and I'm also working on other ways, I'm just trying to move/separate the normal 80 traffic for HTML/CRM from the transactional traffic. Then at firewall, redirect it to another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[List of TCP and UDP port numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) (wikipedia)

Port 43 is [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS) protocol.

A port number in a high range is usually safe, say a number over 10000.
Port numbers are 16bit numbers so they go up to 65535.

Comment: Thanks for that list, I was after any that are blocked as standard functionality in some OS's browsers?

Comment: After much trawling, I think I'm just going to have to bind my calls above 1000. Thanks for the help @fritz-van-campen

Answer (score 0):

For android and I assume iOS as well you cannot bind to ports lower than 1024 unless you are root. This is probably what you are encountering. As people have said above use a port much higher up in the range.